# how to dispaly name, current time in message chat box

Tags: html, css, chat

We developed chat application looks like watts-app. we finished everything but i want to show name and current time in chat message box. how to do that

[requirement screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oz40S.png)

[image]

```css
.left {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: right;
  right: 20px;
}

.left::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  top: -1px;
  right: -10px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #ccc;
}

.left::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  top: 0px;
  right: -8px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid white;
  clear: both;

}

div{
  clear: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
  <p style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;color:green;font-size: 11px;">Kranti</p>
  <span>thanks</span>
   <p style="float: left;margin-bottom: 0px;color:red;font-size: 11px;">2:33 PM</p>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/keqh0cqw/ i did sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create multiple span elements with their own classes and style the username and time to their position.

Use absolute positioning to get the styling as your provided image.

Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/keqh0cqw/1/

An example of your new html:

```
<div class="right">
    <span class="username">kranthi</span>
    <span class="message">thanks</span>
    <span class="time">12:08</span>
</div>
```

Comment: if message is large i need too display two lines . but above link not comming  clear ,the content is hide

Comment: What do you mean? If you want the message in multiple lines just add an `(max-)width` property. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/keqh0cqw/2/

Comment: word-break: break-all;  this property give to message is coming may be in multi line because of i don't want to give max-width.But where used  that property i don't no

Comment: if user name is more than the message it is going to mixing. once see in quetion screen shot

Comment: Well didn't think of that. Don't use absolute positions then. Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/keqh0cqw/7/ . PS: Please accept the answer.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/keqh0cqw/8/:i am getting current time but i am not able append the value in chat box